# How do I add my 'AddToCart' button component in my navbar using react router?

Tags: reactjs, button, router, cart

Ive tried adding my 'Add to Cart' Component button to my navbar using react router but its not working - it just comes up saying product is not defined (its defined in my add to cart component and shop) Im not sure if I need to link the 'addtoCart' component or the cart page. Below is my App.js Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Shop from './Shop';
import Cart from './Cart';
 import Homepage from './Homepage';
import About from './About';
import ContactUs from './ContactUs';
import Blog from './Blog';
import AddToCart from './Components/AddToCart';
import Cart from './Cart';


function App() {

const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);


 const getCartTotal = () => {
 return cart.reduce(
  (sum, { quantity }) => sum + quantity,
  0
);
 };
 return (

<Router>
  <nav>
  <img src="images/Logo2.jpeg" alt="my logo" class="rounded" width="160px"/>
    <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
    <Link to="/Shop"> Shop </Link>
    <Link to="/Blog"> Blog </Link>
    <Link to="/About"> About </Link>
    <Link to="/ContactUs"> Contact Us </Link>
    <Link to="/Shop"><button type="button">Shop</button></Link>
    <Link to="/Cart"><button type="button">AddToCart</button></Link>



  </nav>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    <Route path="/Shop" element={<Shop />} />
    <Route path="/Blog" element={<Shop />} />
    <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/ContactUs" element={<ContactUs />} />
    <Route path="/Cart" element={<AddToCart product={product}  cart={cart} setCart={setCart} />
  </Routes>

</Router>
```

);
}

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

Your other components are not included in the `Component` folder, but your `AddToCart` is. I guess that your `AddToCart` maybe:

```
import AddToCart from './AddToCart';
```

Check your code again and good luck !!

Comment: thank you, I shouldve explained that I only have 2 components atm - my add to cart button and an image gallery. Ive got further than I was, right now it seems to be going to my add to cart button rather than my cart. Any suggestions on how I change that?